# How to use stanford pos tagger for Chinese original text just not segmented

Tags: stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

**Hi,guys:**
I can use POS tagger to tag segmented Chinese text by calling the method
`MaxentTagger.tokenizeText(Reader r)`
but now I want to tag original Chinsese text just not segmented, I know the method
`MaxentTagger.tokenizeText(Reader r,TokenizerFactory tokenizerFactory)`
can do this, but TokenizerFactory is an interface, some subclass implementing it, how to call the method, can someone give some suggestions or examples? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

At present, the probabilistic sequence model word segmenters don't implement the TokenizerFactory interface, only the rule-based tokenizers ... though maybe this should be changed.

What you need to do is to run the [Stanford Word Segmenter](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/segmenter.shtml) to break the original Chinese text into words. This means calling the CRFClassifier class with the appropriate model and properties. The output of this will be a `List<CoreLabel>` (for a sentence) or a `List<List<CoreLabel>>` (for a document). These can be fed into the tagger with the `List<TaggedWord> apply(List<? extends HasWord> in)` or `void tagCoreLabels(List<CoreLabel> sentence)` methods.

Or you might find it easier to use StanfordCoreNLP to connect the pieces together. It works with Chinese if you download the Chinese models jar available at http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml#History

Comment: Thanks very much, best regards to Dr.Manning. I have used Stanford NLP since 2012, it helps me a lot. I have been using the Stanford Segmenter  for the last three years, but recently I need do some work about part of speech tagging. When will you implement the TokenizerFactory by linear chain CRF model word segmenter, I think it will be amazing and convenient.